# I want to run the def(event) function only twice in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzMXG.png)I want to make sure the following code runs only twice.

I'm making a drone simulator. And I was making a program in Python tkinter to make a drone move between two points using a canvas. I am asking this question because I would like to take pictures only twice rather than taking pictures of two points indefinitely. I used unbind but it didn't work. I tried using methods other than stop() to terminate the function, but it didn't work. It's very difficult because Python is not my main skill. help.

Comment: Don't post image of code, copy the code and paste it inside the question. Also it is better to provide a [mre] and describe the issue you came across clearly.